# Area of a sphere in curved 3D space

Tags: homework-and-exercises, cosmology, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, curvature

I'm having trouble finding any information on the derivation of the area of sphere in curved 3D space: $A = 4 \pi S^2_{\kappa}$, where $S_{\kappa} = R_o \sin(r/R_o)$.

How did it come about from $ds^2 =-c^2 dt^2 + [dr^2 + S^2_{\kappa} d{\Omega}^2]$, where $d\Omega^2 = d\theta^2+ \sin^2 \theta\,d\phi^2$?

Comment: Can you do the analogous calculation for flat 3D space, starting from the flat metric? Do you understand what the area element $dA$ is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\amat}[4]{\left(\begin{matrix}#1 & #2 \\ #3 & #4 \end{matrix}\right)}$

> $A = 4 \pi S^2_{\kappa}$...

> ...How did it come about from $ds^2 =-c^2 dt^2 + [dr^2 + S^2_{\kappa} d{\Omega}^2]$, where $d\Omega^2 = d\theta^2+ \sin^2 \theta\,d\phi^2$?

You need to identify $g_{\theta \theta}$, $g_{\theta \phi}$, $g_{\phi \theta}$, and $g_{\phi\phi}$.

Then use:
$$
A = \int d\theta d\phi \sqrt{g}\;,
$$
where
$$
g = \det(\amat{g_{\theta \theta}}{g_{\theta \phi}}{g_{\phi \theta}}{g_{\phi \phi}})
$$

Comment: Thank you very much!